# Sum of individual rows and columns in user-specified matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, magic-square

This assignment involves a 'matrix.txt' file that is to be imported into the program.  This file can have a matrix of any size.  The prof has furnished a working program to properly import this file, and has set the task of the students to determine if this file is a Magic Square.  I know this means getting the sum of each row and each column and then comparing the values to see if they are equal.  My problem is that I do not know how to specify a single rows' value that does not have to be immediately printed out, thereby losing the value when the loop repeats.  I would like a way that will store each value so they can be checked for equality after the loop has iterated over all the possible rows and columns.  since I have no idea what the size of the array will be, I cannot 'hard code' values, and would have to use stuff like:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
{
for (j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
```

I am looking for a way to individualize the values of each row and column so I can compare them later.  Then I would print out "The matrix is a magic square", or "The matrix is not a magic square"

Comment: The values are stored in the matrix (elements), but I need to store the sum of Row0, and compare that value to all other row and column sums in the matrix.

Comment: store the sum of the first / any row or column, the matrix is a magic square if all columns and rows sum to this value (i.e. accross the whole matrix any column sum and row sum are equal)

Comment: Also, for clarification...the contents of the 'matrix.txt' file are a randomly sized matrix.  It could be a 3x3, 4x4, 5x5, etc.  The program needs to be able to import any file titled 'matrix.txt' and determine if it is a Magic Square

Comment: You don't need to store all sums, because they are all supposed to be equal. Just keep the value in a variable, and as soon as you find a sum that is different, you know, that it's not a magic square, so you can stop.

Comment: OK..so I only need to store 1 value, then use a Boolean to see if the other values equal that one?  So maybe call a variable 'targetValue' which is the sum of Row0, and then find a way to see if the next row (Row1 = targetValue?  If so, continue with the loop..if not, exit loop and print out, it is not a Magic Square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would some code like this work?

```
boolean isMagicSquard = true;
int sum = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    // Calculate the sum for each row
    int rowsum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
        rowsum += matrix[j][i];
    }
    if (sum == -1){ 
        sum = rowsum; 
    }else if (sum != rowsum){ // If the sum differs from the 
                              // first-row sum, it is no magic squaree
        isMagicSquard = false; break; 
    }
}
// The same code with rows and column swaped
for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++){
    int columnsum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++){
        columnsum += matrix[i][j];
    }
    if (sum != columnsum ){ 
        isMagicSquard = false; break; 
    }
}
System.out.println(isMagicSquare);
```

Comment: This looks like it might work, and I have placed it inside of a method named "isMagic(int matrix[][])".  The next problem is I can't seem to get this method to be called, so the program does nothing right now.  Not sure on the syntax to call this method so that the matrix is read

Comment: I got it to work.  Just had to look up the syntax for calling a method containing a matrix.